# How to upload images in tree view and display it in the tree or list view in Openerp 7 or Odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have used the below code and on clicking on save. It saves the file but on clicking on the saved file. It is downloading it with a bin file format.

I have 2 doubts:

1. How do I download it using the same filename and extension that was uploaded.
2. How can I view all the images in the tree view from where it was uploaded. Using widget="image" does not work.

The **openerp**.py file:

```
{
    'name' : 'Vyas File Upload Demo',
    'version' : '0.1',
    'category' : 'Demo',
    'description' : 
    """
        Module to test the working of File upload and download in Openerp 7

    """,
    'author' : 'Vyas Senthil',
    'license' : 'AGPL-3',
    'depends' : [],
    'init_xml' : [],
    'demo_xml' : [],
    'update_xml' : ['file_upload_demo_view.xml'],
    'active': False,
    'installable': True,
}
```

file upload demo.py [Python file]:

```
from osv import osv,fields
    from datetime import date,datetime
    from openerp import netsvc
    from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
    from openerp.tools.translate import _
    from operator import itemgetter
    import base64
    import time
    import re
    import psycopg2 as psy
    import sys
    import pprint   # To print python objects in a readable format , use "pprint.pprint(obj or dictionary)".
    import pdb  # To debug python files. Use pdb.set_trace()


    class manage_inspection(osv.osv):
        ''' Inspection module'''
        _name = 'manage.inspection'
        _columns = {

            'name': fields.char('Inspection Number',required=True), # Inspection Number
            'file_upload_demo_grid': fields.one2many('file.upload.demo','manage_inspection_id', 'File upload Grid'), 
        }


    class file_upload_demo(osv.osv):
        #class to maintain plant type 

        _name = 'file.upload.demo'


        def _get_contract_file_name(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
            ''' To set the name_filename field'''

            result = {}
            for product_data in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                    result[product_data.id] = product_data['file_path']
                    return result
            return result


        _columns = {

                'image_upload': fields.binary(string='Image Upload new'),
                'file_path': fields.char('File Name and Extension', size=128),
                'name_filename':fields.function(_get_contract_file_name, type="char", size=255, method=True, string="File Name"),

                'manage_inspection_id': fields.many2one('manage.inspection','Manage Inspection Id'), # Connection to Parent form.


            }

    file_upload_demo()
```

file_upload_demo_view.xml [XML file]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- Top Menu -->
        <menuitem name="Vyas File Upload Demo"
            id="file_upload_demo_top_menu"
            sequence="32"/>

        <!-- Side Menu Heading -->
        <menuitem name="File Upload Demo"
            id="file_upload_demo_side_heading"
            parent="file_upload_demo_top_menu"
            sequence="1"/>



        <!-- inspection form view -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_file_upload_demo_form">
            <field name="name">manage.inspection.form</field>
            <field name="model">manage.inspection</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Manage Inspection" version="7.0">

                    <!-- File Upload method -->
                    <field name="name" placeholder="Inspection Number" style="width:30%%" />

                    <!-- Grid - Upload Photos -->
                    <field name="file_upload_demo_grid" />

                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- file_upload_demo tree view -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_file_upload_demo_tree">
            <field name="name">file.upload.demo.tree</field>
            <field name="model">file.upload.demo</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="file upload demo" editable="top">

                    <!-- File Upload method -->
                    <field name="file_path" />
                    <field name="image_upload"  filename="file_path" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>


        <!-- action menu -->
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_upload_files_demo">  
            <field name="name">Inspection </field>          <!-- view label -->
            <field name="res_model">manage.inspection</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <!-- Side menu to open Manage Sales Invoice -->
        <menuitem 
            name="Upload Files Demo"
            id="upload_file_demo"
            parent="file_upload_demo_side_heading"
            sequence="3"
            action="action_upload_files_demo"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: I was able to fix this problem using the solution from [link]https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-7-how-can-i-add-images-in-sale-oder-line-or-in-treeview-generally-483 . But the problem I still face is that when uploading the image, it uploads it in its original size which takes up most of the screen and stays that way until another image is added or I click on save, at that time it reduces to the required image placeholder size. How do I make it the size of placeholder when uploading the image itself.

Comment: My class structure is of the form :- school (Form view) - > school_class (Tree view) -> students(Tree View), all in one form view. The images are uploaded in students (Tree view) for every school_class and there are many school_class in the school.  And in the search view , I should be able to see all the images for the given school. But am not sure how to show multiple classes in one search view.

Answer (score 0):

look for Document button in project module this is allow you to attach multiple attachment and view them it tree , view the most beautiful thing that is preserve your attachment name and extension (try to do like it )
Note:
this attachment can be image or any type of attachment

Comment: My class structure is of the form :- school (Form view) - > school_class (Tree view) -> students(Tree View). The images are uploaded in students (Tree view) for every school_class and there are many school_class in the school. So this type of attachment will not work for my requirements. And in the search view , I should be able to see all the images for the given school. But am not sure how to show multiple classes in one search view.